# jQuery masonry example not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

Based on [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), I have got the following:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector : '.item',
        columnWidth: 240
});
```

**jQuery ajax:** (jquery-masonry works the first time `success` happens after a page load.  jquery-masonry does not work if the `success` happens again without a page reload.)

```
success: function( widget_shell ) 
{ 

    if( widget_shell.d[0] ) {

        $( "#container" ).empty();

        var i = 0;

        // creating the div elements
        for ( i = 0; i <= widget_shell.d.length - 1; i++ ) {

            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 50

            var $widget = $( "<div class='item col1' style='height:" + j + "px'></div>" ).appendTo( $( "#container" ) );
            $( "<span>" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id + " - " + j + "</span>" ).appendTo( $widget );

        }

        // initialising the jquery masonry plugin
        $('#container').masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            columnWidth: 240
        });

    }

}
```

**HTML:** (Create dynamically via jQuery-ajax)

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative; height: 0px;" class="masonry">
    <div class="item col1" style="height:154px"><span>39 - 154</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:100px"><span>52 - 100</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:229px"><span>53 - 229</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:126px"><span>55 - 126</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:245px"><span>56 - 245</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:242px"><span>57 - 242</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:146px"><span>58 - 146</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:63px"><span>59 - 63</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:118px"><span>60 - 118</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:249px"><span>61 - 249</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:136px"><span>62 - 136</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:114px"><span>63 - 114</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:152px"><span>64 - 152</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:52px"><span>65 - 52</span></div>
    <div class="item col1" style="height:95px"><span>66 - 95</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    width: 220px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    background:white;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Expected:**

When it should look like [this](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html) interms of the divs being up against each other horizontally and vertically.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you have `height: 0px` in your `#container div` ?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/RNA8R/).

Comment: @CalvinCheng, I didn't add that, it's getting generated automatically.

Comment: @ChristianVarga, could the reason for my problem be that I am creating those div's dynamically via jQuery-Ajax?

Comment: are you calling jquery in a dom ready state?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I have the following around my jquery-ajax `$(document).ready(function() {`  is that what you mean?

Comment: Check your network tab. I believe your jquery.masonry.min.js or your jquery file aren't loading up.

Comment: If you're creating the divs dynamically, ensure the masonry initialising code runs _after_ the elements have been created.

Comment: @ChristianVarga, That seems to be the reason.  So I have tried initialising the code to run after the element creation, but it only works once.  For example, if elements are created after a page reload, it's fine, but if the elements change via ajax without a page refresh, it does what you can see in the image above.  I will post up my ajax script in a moment so you can see the problem.

Comment: @ChristianVarga, I've added a new section to the question above in bold, called `jQuery ajax:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`.masonry('reload')`](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html) function after you append more elements. Eg, this *may* work:

```
success: function( widget_shell ) 
{ 

    if( widget_shell.d[0] ) {

        $( "#container" ).empty();

        var i = 0;

        // creating the div elements
        for ( i = 0; i <= widget_shell.d.length - 1; i++ ) {

            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 50

            var $widget = $( "<div class='item col1' style='height:" + j + "px'></div>" ).appendTo( $( "#container" ) );
            $( "<span>" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id + " - " + j + "</span>" ).appendTo( $widget );

        }

        // reload jquery masonry plugin
        $('#container').masonry('reload')

    }

}
```

Otherwise, check the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RNA8R/1/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `jquery.masonry.min.js` isn't loaded up correctly.  Check the network tab on your firebug or your chrome developer tools.

Here's my exact code in my `index.html` file (not what is rendered on my dom; my actual code in my html file):-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./masonry-master/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
              $('#container').masonry({
                // options
                itemSelector : '.item'
              });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #999;
            }

            .item {
                width: 220px;
                margin: 10px;
                float: left;
                background:white;
            }​
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item" style="height:154px"><span>39 - 154</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:100px"><span>52 - 100</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:229px"><span>53 - 229</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:126px"><span>55 - 126</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:245px"><span>56 - 245</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:242px"><span>57 - 242</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:146px"><span>58 - 146</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:63px"><span>59 - 63</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:118px"><span>60 - 118</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:249px"><span>61 - 249</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:136px"><span>62 - 136</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:114px"><span>63 - 114</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:152px"><span>64 - 152</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:52px"><span>65 - 52</span></div>
        <div class="item" style="height:95px"><span>66 - 95</span></div>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Directory structure:-

My `index.html` loads up `jquery.masonry.min.js` in a directory called `masonry-master` right in the same directory level

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with when I am initialising the jquery.masonry plugin.  Please see the new code shown in the original question title in bold `jQuery ajax` pointed out by `Christian Varga` in the comments.